# Keyword 'Values' absent Oracle 9i

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I'm trying to execute the following trigger when inserting some data in my table :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AJOUTER_NEW_CONSISTANCE 
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF 
     CONSISTANCE_LIBELLE_1,CONSISTANCE_LIBELLE_2,CONSISTANC_LIBELLE_3 
   ON DB.ETAT_PARCELLAIRE  
BEGIN

  insert into DB.CONSISTANCE.LIBELLE
  select consistance_libelle_1
    from DB.ETAT_PARCELLAIRE
   where DB.ETAT_PARCELLAIRE.consistance_libelle_1 not in (
        select LIBELLE from  DB.CONSISTANCE.LIBELLE);

END;
```

But it keeps giving me the following error :

```
PL/SQL : ORA00926 : Keyword Values absent.
```

How can I fix this ?
Thank you for help in advance :)

Comment: Is `CONSISTANCE` as table with a column called `LIBELLE`?

Comment: Yes Alex you're right ;)

Comment: `DB.CONSISTANCE.LIBELLE` is an invalid table identifier in Oracle (btw: do you really have a user named `DB`? Very strange name...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `CONSISTANCE` is a table with a column called `LIBELLE` then you're referring to it incorrectly.

- your insert is including the column, which I assume means the table has other columns and you only want to insert a value into that one, but your syntax is wrong (`DB.CONSISTANCE.LIBELLE` should be `DB.CONSISTANCE(LIBELLE)`). it is this line that's generating the ORA-00926.
- your sub-select is including the column in the table name (`DB.CONSISTANCE.LIBELLE` should be just `DB.CONSISTANCE`)

So it should be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AJOUTER_NEW_CONSISTANCE 
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF 
     CONSISTANCE_LIBELLE_1,CONSISTANCE_LIBELLE_2,CONSISTANC_LIBELLE_3 
   ON DB.ETAT_PARCELLAIRE  
BEGIN

  insert into DB.CONSISTANCE(LIBELLE)
  select consistance_libelle_1
    from DB.ETAT_PARCELLAIRE
   where consistance_libelle_1 not in (
        select LIBELLE from DB.CONSISTANCE);

END;
```

I'm also not sure if `CONSISTANC_LIBELLE_3` is a typo and it should be `CONSISTANCE_LIBELLE_3`.

You could also do a `not exists` instead of a `not in`:

```
  insert into DB.CONSISTANCE(LIBELLE)
  select CONSISTANCE_LIBELLE_1
    from DB.ETAT_PARCELLAIRE
   where not exists (
         select 1
           from DB.CONSISTANCE
          where LIBELLE = DB.ETAT_PARCELLAIRE.CONSISTANCE_LIBELLE_1
         );
```

Or use a `merge`:

```
  merge into DB.CONSISTANCE c
  using (select CONSISTANCE_LIBELLE_1 from DB.ETAT_PARCELLAIRE) ep
  on (c.LIBELLE = ep.CONSISTANCE_LIBELLE_1)
  when not matched then
    insert (LIBELLE) values (ep.CONSISTANCE_LIBELLE_1);
```

Using a trigger to (partially) maintain that table looks odd though - it would be simpler to have a view which selects distinct values from `ETAT_PARCELLAIRE`:

```
create or replace view CONSISTANCE_VIEW as
select distinct CONSISTANCE_LIBELLE_1
  from ETAT_PARCELLAIRE;
```

But they would have different content - once a value has appeared in `CONSISTANCE_LIBELLE_1` it will always remain in `CONSISTANCE` as you are not removing defunct values, only inserting new ones; whereas `CONSISTANCE_VIEW` would only show values currently in the table. It isn't clear which behaviour you want.

Comment: Thank you very much @Alex Poole :) I will take in consideration your pieces of advice ;) I'm just newbie with oracle technologies. Between, how ca I use the merge you mentionned ?

Comment: I'm getting strange behavior for the NOT IN clause, some values are being inserted eventhough they already exist in the DB.CONSISTANCE table

Comment: @mounaim - are you maybe looking at uncommitted data in another session? Or are you getting duplicates from a single insert - you'd need a `distinct` keyword in your `select` if you want to avoid that.

Comment: I would upvote this answer twice and more if I could :) many thanks Alex ;)